# Web page upload file not working on iPad

Tags: ipad

Seems a simple upload file link I have on a website is grayed out and not working/allowing user to click it to upload a file on the iPad.

> [image]

Answer (score 4):

File upload support is limited on iOS. Safari isn't allowed to access files in other applications, but since iOS 6 it has allowed image uploads either from the camera roll or directly from the camera.

Comment: so what would i have to do to allow the person to upload an image from their iPad using this website?

Comment: Build a native application, or file a feature request with Apple. There is currently no way to access any files on an iOS device through a web app.

Comment: Apple is so innovative that their Safari browser can't even do a simple task of uploading files... Oh the irony.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw Anyone have an official Apple doc or something official looking that I can show a client?  All I've found is comments on message boards about this, but I need something to show a client that no, you can't upload documents on a web browser.  Thanks!

Comment: @boilers Actually, this isn't completely true anymore. As [this Apple page](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html) mentions, some uploads have been supported since iOS 6. The page fails to note however that only images from the camera roll or camera can be uploaded. Would your client be satisfied if you showed them a sample page and those were the only options?

Answer (score 0):

The iPad is a different thing that a regular notebook or a PC. Thanks to Apple sand boxing of apps for security reasons. Unless you jail break it, you will not, and can not, access the file system.

Comment: it doesn't need to access the file system. for example file input elements work in android, and they open a dialog which allows the user to do various things such as record audio, video, take a picture, select a picture from the gallery, etc...

Comment: well, that's android and not ipad/iphone!